# POC for Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, poc

I am technical guys from bank and my job scope is mainly on ETL and reporting. We just set up ETL team in my department and we want to have some tool that can help us on source code control and release management. One of the tool that I know  in the market is TFS.

I'm going to ask TFS vendor to provide POC to us, and since my knowledge on TFS is very limited, I want some suggestion from your guys, what kind of POC I should ask vendor demo to us and are there any sets of scenario idea that highlighting the power of TFS 2010? Thanks you very much

Comment: Why TFS2010? That's 5 years old.  TFS 2015 is the most recent version.

Comment: Recommend you to use TFS2015,  there is a new build system only for TFS2015 called *Vnext Build* , more convenient, highly customizable, also get better outcomes by using the new system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just focus on the things your need, **Source Control** and **Release Management**.

### Source control

You can ask them to show you something like code review, view and manage past versions, use branch isolate risk and so on. Also make sure which version control you want to use, for TFS2015 there are two options(TFVC vs Git).

Moreover, show some related sections, show associating a work item with a checkin and then lead in to the automated builds and tests , which then lead in to the build reports. Bug tracking is also a good thing to demo.

### Release Management

Choose some topic below you are interested in

- Automate your deployments
- Automate approval workflows
- Retain full traceability
- Apply security policies and manage users
- Easily deploy to on-premises and Azure
- Extend Release Management with customizations

Cause of the particularity of banking, you can also ask them demo something about reporting, chart and Excel. TFS show nice graphs :)

[image]
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

The POC should show:

1. How a change is propagated from developer to various environments (development, test, production):

check-in -> unit testing -> build -> release to environment 1 -> integration testing -> release to environment 2 (without rebuilding)

2. How you can trace from a requirements(user story) to the line of code that is implementing it and back.